# How to configure ngrok for SQL Server access

Tags: ngrok, sql-server-config-manager

I would like to test a website in development hosted in a remote location against a sql server instance on my local machine. I was thinking I could run ngrok locally and update the connection string on the remote website appropriately, but I'm not sure what parameters I need to specify.

I've tried `ngrok tcp 12345` and `ngrok http 12345`

In SQL Server Configuration Manager I've enabled TCP/IP for the SQL Express instance I want to use and set the port to listen on to 12345 (actually, a different number, but we'll say 12345 for the sake of this post). And I then restarted SQL Server.

I don't believe it's necessary for me to make holes in the firewall, but just in case I've temporarily disabled it entirely while I test this.

To test locally, I am taking the url ngrok provides and putting it in the connection dialog in SQL Management Studio, but I can't get it to connect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Set up Ngrok
2. Run ngrok on tcp on the SQL port (by default is 1433)
   `ngrok tcp 1433`

You  will get an url like `tcp://3.tcp.ngrok.io:12345`

In the "Connect to Server Dialog" type:

- Server name: `3.tcp.ngrok.io,12345` Notice the comma between the port and  the url. Type the url without `tcp://`
- Login: your regular user, in my case `sa` and your password
- Connect

Answer (score 1):

The "URL" that ngrok generates for a TCP tunnel probably shouldn't be used unmodified. The `tcp://` scheme part isn't a URI scheme in common use I don't think. Only the hostname and port part of the generated ngrok "URL" would be useful in a SQL Server connection configuration.

Not being intimately familiar with the referenced connection dialog in SQL Management Studio, it's hard to say exactly what input is expected, but maybe stripping out the `tcp://` scheme will do the trick?

Comment: Yes, I tried both ways. Typically with an IP address you just put the IP address with no scheme. But you got me to thinking I can at least try to connect to my SQL instance from another computer on the same network and rule out the SQL Configuration as being an issue.

Comment: Were you able to connect from another computer on the same network @BVernon?

Comment: I didn't get to it and I no longer need to. At some point when I have time I will probably test it out just because I'm curious, but a bit busy at the moment and it's no longer a blocking issue for me. I'll come update the post if/when I find anything out. I will mention though that the connection string I'm using now starts like this ""Data Source=tcp:subdomain.domian.com;" and I had not previously tried doing it that way without the double slash from management studio so that might be it.

Comment: On the other  hand I've never started a connection string with "tcp:" at all and suspect that could be omitted but I just used the string my web host specified.