# Is it impossible to connect MSSQL localdb from published asp net core mvc 6.0 project?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-connection, publish, localserver

I made my simple project that save my ideas to `"(localdb)\mssqllocaldb"`.

```cs
namespace publish.Models
{
    public class idea
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I use asp.net.core 6.0 - mvc.
I published this project to local folder and deploy using iis manager.
However after publishing, I tried browse but failed.
Because it is failed to connect local database.
How can I resolve this problem?

I saw lecture the name is "How to Publish an ASP .NET Core 6 Website _ APP on a Windows OS and Fix Database Connection Problem".
I tried to resolve using this method.
From "Microsoft Sql Server management studio", I create new login as sql server authentication.
Then change the connection string in appsetting.json like that

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "publishContext": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=publish.Data;uid=ali12;pwd=123;"
  }
```

And published using this connectionstrings.
However, I saw error message like this

> Error.
> An error occurred while processing your request.
> Request ID: 00-e7f938a225da4cf8d5148cfd354c0f34-01a9fa13f2a60d36-00
> ...

===============================================
Dear Jason Pan, I tried to resolve my problem from your guidance.
However, I didn`t success.

Comment: Did you follow the advice with development mode? Please post that error message *with more detailed information about the error that occurred*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also using localdb and facing the same issue. You can add below code in web.config file, then you will get more detailed error message.

```
<environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
```

My sample web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\AspCore7_Web_Identity.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess">
          <environmentVariables>
     <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
</environmentVariables>
 </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: E938A144-170E-4E89-****-9B88****7039-->
```

And get below error message.

[image]

**Solution**

You need to install the Microsoft SQL Server in your server and make sure it can be accessed.

Comment: Dear Jason Pan. Thanks for your help. I changed web.config file. However same problem occurred.  And I installed "Microsoft SQL server management studio" already. However how can I make sure it? I am waiting for your answer detailed.

Comment: Hi @AliAli, please [follow the steps in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75480715/7687666),  you could [add new database or  attach the existing .mdf & .ldf files,](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6222/sql-server-attach-and-detach-database-examples/), and enable it can accept remote connections, then get connectionstrings from vs2022.  Finally you will fix the issue.

Comment: Dear Jason Pan! I succeed to connection "localdb". However, I must install sql express server. Is it impossible to connect localdb using mssql server?